# Finding a closed form for the following integral: $\int_0^1\sqrt{1+x^k}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, radicals, closed-form

Is there a nice closed form, for the following integral:

$$\int_0^1\sqrt{1+x^k}dx$$

And how can I derive it?

I have no idea how to get started, thanks for any help. This problem came up when I was working on a number theory problem in my university for some values of $k$.

Comment: This is a nice and interesting problem.

Comment: what do you mean by "derive"? There's no variable (except $k$, but ...).

Comment: There is, most probably, no closed form. Quite boring.

Comment: @math I mean, if there is a closed form how can I show that that is the closed form.

Comment: sorry @trljlpy i didn't understand

Comment: This smells the incomplete Beta integral.

Comment: @math derive also means "to obtain something from" in this case working towards an answer, rather than just the calculus definition of derive which comes from the word differentiation

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, using [IBP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) you can show that:

$$\mathscr{S}_\text{n}:=\int_0^1\sqrt{1+x^\text{n}}\space\text{d}x=\sqrt{2}-\frac{\text{n}}{2}\int_0^1\frac{x^\text{n}}{\sqrt{1+x^\text{n}}}\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Using the fact that:

$$\frac{x^\text{n}}{\sqrt{1+x^\text{n}}}=\sqrt{1+x^\text{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^\text{n}}}\tag2$$

We can write:

$$\mathscr{S}_\text{n}=\sqrt{2}-\frac{\text{n}}{2}\cdot\left\{\underbrace{\int_0^1\sqrt{1+x^\text{n}}\space\text{d}x}_{=\space\mathscr{S}_\text{n}}-\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^\text{n}}}\space\text{d}x\right\}\tag3$$

Using the [Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) we know that we can write:

$$\mathscr{S}_\text{n}=\sqrt{2}-\frac{\text{n}}{2}\cdot\left\{\mathscr{S}_\text{n}-\int_0^1\sum_{\text{k}\ge0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{k}\left(2\text{k}\right)!}{2^{2\text{k}}\left(\text{k}!\right)^2}\cdot x^{\text{nk}}\space\text{d}x\right\}=$$
$$\sqrt{2}-\frac{\text{n}}{2}\cdot\left\{\mathscr{S}_\text{n}-\sum_{\text{k}\ge0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{k}\left(2\text{k}\right)!}{2^{2\text{k}}\left(\text{k}!\right)^2}\int_0^1x^{\text{nk}}\space\text{d}x\right\}=$$
$$\sqrt{2}-\frac{\text{n}}{2}\cdot\left\{\mathscr{S}_\text{n}-\underbrace{\sum_{\text{k}\ge0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{k}\left(2\text{k}\right)!}{2^{2\text{k}}\left(\text{k}!\right)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\text{nk}}}_{:=\space\mathcal{I}_\text{n}}\right\}\tag4$$

Solving for $\mathscr{S}_\text{n}$, gives:

$$\mathscr{S}_\text{n}=\frac{2\sqrt{2}+\text{n}\cdot\mathcal{I}_\text{n}}{2+\text{n}}\tag5$$

Comment: Thank you so much for this fast answer. I will study it further.

Comment: @JanErland I do appreciate you answer... But, considering the dependence on the calculation of the sum of a series, how is this any better than just applying the trapezoidal rule with an increasing number of points?

Comment: Exactly. I wouldn’t call this a closed form expression.

Comment: Yes @Tavish, this cannot be considered a closed form solution. If it could, maybe a much simpler solution could be defining $I_k = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+x^k} dx$ and saying the answer is $I_K$ :)

Comment: But of coarse, depending on how fast the series converges, this may be a good alternative to other approximation methods.

Comment: Just curious here. In these cases, when there will be a series anyways, why not simply expand the integrand as a Taylor Series and then integrate? Would it converge too slow?

Comment: I thought closed form meant a finite number of operations. This has an infinite series, therefore not closed form. Can you at least provide a Big O expression for how the terms of the sum scale with k? Otherwise this is just turning a cleanly written integral into a mess with no obvious advantage.

Answer (score 3):

If we expand $\sqrt{1+x^k}$ in series and then intergrate  then we get a close representation in terms of hypergeometric function
$$
\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+x^k}={}_2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{k};\frac{k+1}{k};-1 \right)
$$

Comment: This is also what WA says https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+sqrt%281%2Bx%5Ek%29

Comment: I found the same with *Mathematica*. Can we call this a "closed form"? After all hypergeometric function is a series and computing it or computing the definite integral using Simpson or trapezoid rule is almost the same. What do you think?

Comment: If there is nothing better, then  the hypergeometric function can be considered as a closed form

Comment: It cannot. We can just say, “there is no closed form”.

Comment: There is an incomplete beta function form